# How to apply MySQL per db per user connection limit

Tags: mysql, database-administration

Hi i am looking for a solution to apply limits to all users for no of simultaneous connection per db . MySQL provides the way to specify connection limit per user but doesn't specify a way to restrict connection per db basis .

Comment: are you looking for persistent connection?

Comment: it may be and may not be depending on the user application